# Riemann-Hilbert correspondence over nodal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

There is a micro-local version of Riemann-Hilbert correspondence over nodal curve $X$ given by Roman Bezrukavnikov Mikhail Kapranov in the paper: [Micro-local sheaves and quiver varieties](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07050.pdf)

The de Rham side of the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence is the category of $de\ Rham\ microlocal\ sheaves$.   The definition of $de\ Rham\ microlocal\ sheaves$ is defined as follows:

[image]

My Question is:   Is there a geometric meaning (origin) for the back and forth morphisms $u_x, v_x$ in above definition?  Why is this kind of definition the "right one" for Riemann Hilbert correspondence?